Indirect Addressing P16F877
Suppose i have two numbers n1 & n2, one in bank 0 and the other in bank 2, i want to do a sum operation on them using the indirect addressing approach, here is the code from my lecture which is wrong after tested in mplab 8.92, i need someone to correct it thanks:
nbr1 equ 0xA0
nbr2 equ 0x121
som12 equ 0x1A2
; les instructions ci-dessus utilisant la directive (equ) peuvent être remplacées par la directive cblock :
; cblock 0x20
; nbr1, nbr2, som12
; endc
w equ 0
f equ 1
; la macro suivante (bank0) est un sous-programme qui permet de configurer STATUS pour pointer sur bank#0

; ------------- Programme principal ---------------------------------------
org 0x00 ; définir la position initiale dans la mémoire programme
debut
    ;nbr1:
    CLRF STATUS;IRP = 0
    movlw 0xA0
    movwf FSR  ;FSR=0xA0
    movlw 0xFF ; transférer la valeur (0x0A) dans l'accumulateur w
    movwf INDF ; transférer le contenu de W à l'adresse du nbr1

    ;nbr2:
    bsf STATUS, IRP;IRP = 1
    movlw 0x21
    movwf FSR ;FSR=0x21
    movlw 0x01 ; transférer la valeur (0x0A) dans l'accumulateur w
    movwf INDF
    
    ;Charger addresse de nbr1 dans FSR
    bcf STATUS, IRP;IRP = 0
    movlw 0xA0
    movwf FSR ;FSR=0xA0
    addwf INDF,w ; additionner w à la variable nbr2
    
    bsf STATUS, IRP;IRP = 1
    movlw 0xA2
    movwf FSR ;FSR=0xA2
    movwf INDF ; stoker le résultat de la somme à partir de w sur la variable som12
    goto debut ; réexécuter la boucle depuis le label « début »
    end```


I tried to rewrite the code but unfortunately i dont know much, im used to the x86 assembly so using PICs are abit difficult


You will probably get a better answer on the EE Stack Exchange site. I think that this answer about  indirect addressing FSR using INDF might be what you are looking for...

Thanks but the link you refered me to doesnt really help @MartinBrown
